# Where can I find GIF inspiration about a certain subject (find us page)?

Tags: animation, gif, resource-recommendations, trends, inspiration

I started working as a graphic designer two days ago. My boss asked me to create more than one gif to clarify the location of a company and when I created one and he said "I could've liked it two years ago but now it's too normal" and he asked me to look at gif trends...

[image: GIF]

I was so focused on branding and photo retouching that I know absolutely nothing about gifs, I'm not talking about the know-how of creating them but I'm talking about inspiration and knowledge of the fundamentals and rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what kind of GIF your boss wants. But you can always search for trends on popular designer's sites like [dribbble](https://dribbble.com/). Honestly you have to do the research yourself, Google is your friend.

GIFs are short videos/animations, so the same fundamentals apply. Because they can be 2D or 3D the list of software to create them is too large to include here, from video editors to 3D animation tools.

You can see a bunch of examples [here](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/07/50-inspiring-animated-gifs/).

I'd say that a trend for 2D animation lately is using a more flat style like this:

[image: flat coffee animation]

Or combining some subtle 3D elements like this:

[image: 2D - 3D]

Answer (score 2):

**Guillaume Kurkdjian**

Is a gif illustrator with a very broad and inspiring book of works.

https://guillaumekurkdjian.com/

https://twitter.com/gkurkdjian

[image: Kurkdjian01]